# What is the purpose of ethernet ports on a business router or home router?

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, switch

In some research I did on the internet, I found the information that the ethernet ports of a router are used to create different networks, this can be done by connecting switches to each ethernet port on the router, and each router's network interface (ethernet port) should receive an IP which would be the gateway address for the HOSTs connected to the switches, in other words, each ethernet port of the router would be a different network.

But I ended up finding in other articles reading on the internet the information that the ethernet ports of a router actually serve for the router to connect HOSTs and not different networks as in the previous explanation.
I would like to know which explanation would be the correct one, thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be both. Ethernet networking is networking. you can connect a host computer directly via an ethernet port on a home router. Or you can connect a switch to the ethernet port on the router and then connect a host computer to the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the confusion here seems to be based on the different classes of routers out there.

In general, a normal home Internet Access Router will only connect two networks (the ISPs network, and your own LAN). Those devices usually have a switch built into the LAN interface, so you can connect multiple devices to it, and have them all be on the same network. this seems to fit your second situation nicely. You can think of it like there are two router ports, and one of them is hardwired to a 4-port switch to which 4 lan devices could connect, if you like.  That would harmonize both the propositions.

An enterprise router is a much more complicated device and while it often has many ports, it is up to the administrator to decide what those ports do, what networks they are part of, and how that network interacts with other networks connected to the router. You could take an 8-port router, and assign two ports to each of 4 networks, as well as configure it so networks 1 and 3 can talk together, but 1 can't talk to 2 or 4.

So, they are both right, just incomplete in and of themselves.